# "I did not go out because it was raining"—how could one disambiguate this sentence?

Tags: negation, subordinate-clauses, subordinators, disambiguation

**"I did not go out because it was raining" is ambiguous, with at least two interpretations.**

It could simply mean I did not go out because it was raining (and, therefore, a bad time to head out).

Yet, it could—though some may oppose—mean I did not go out because it was raining, but for some other reason instead.

This problem seems to arise on pairing a negative auxiliary (e.g. not) and the subordinating conjunction "because".

Please read these examples, too.

1. I did not take the offer because it was too good to be true. (She may have taken the offer for some other reason, instead.)
2. She did not eat the donut because it looked mediocre. (Perhaps she ate it for some other reason.)
3. Jodie and Jimmy did not like the toy because it made a squeaky sound when pressed. (Did they like it for some other reason?)

However, I am not satisfied with my solutions. In particular, we do not say those so often (I think). The "not" + "because" sentence has something special about it that I feel has its place in disambiguation.

Comment: It would only have the second interpretation if you go on to state the real reason. In speech, of course, the tone of voice would make the meaning clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I did not go out as it was raining" can be interpreted in most cases, depending on the context, as

- "I did not go out while  it was raining" ([OALD, conjunction, 1](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/as_3))

*or*

- "I did not go out, the reason being that it was raining" ([OALD, conjunction, 3](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/as_3)).

It cannot mean "The reason I went out is not because it was raining" in my opinion; this meaning can be extracted only when the conjunction is "*because*"; however, for that usage it seems that most often there is a corrective addition introduced by "but", which is what  will make this sense specific to the reader.

- Jodie and Jimmy did not like the toy because it made a squeaky sound when pressed but because they loved its bright red colour.

Note that you cannot easily have such a meaning with the choices "*too good to be true*" and "*mediocre*" because they carry semantically negative notions; a rather rare context is needed, such as for instance someone who loves mediocre donuts rather than well made ones.

- I did not take the offer because of the rebate but because  the price, to begin with, is right.
- She did not eat the donut because it was big and creamy on top but because she does not like the other pastries.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, these could be valid solutions.

- 0A: Because it was raining, I did not go out.
- 0B: Rain is not what I went out for.
- 1A: The offer was too good to be true, so I did not take it.
- 1B: I took the offer not because it was too good to be true, but...
- 2A: The donut looked mediocre, so she did not eat it.
- 2B: That the donut looked mediocre is not why she ate it.
- 3A: Jodie and Jimmy disliked the toy because it made a squeaky sound when pressed.
- 3B: The toy's making a squeaky sound when pressed is not why Jodie and Jimmy liked it.

Comment: oB has an entirely different meaning

Answer (score 0):

**There is an important distinction between "as" and "because" as subordinating conjunctions.**

At least in British, American and Canadian English.

> I did not go out as it was raining

does not mean "there was a different reason that I went out". In this way the word "as" is different from the word "because". "I did not go out because it was raining" could indeed mean that.

It does have a different potential meaning, i.e. "I went out at a different time, other than the time it was raining."

If we switch to using "because" to avoid the problem, the following are valid:

1. "Because it was raining I did not go out" (unambiguously meaning 1)
2. "The rain was not the reason I went out" (unambiguously meaning 2)
3. "I went out not because it was raining" (unambiguously meaning 2)
4. "I did not go out since it was raining" (unambiguously meaning 2, though I am aware that Indian English can use this construct to mean "in the time after it was raining". Grammatical correctness would require the past tense.)

Comment: What you say could very well be the case. Being a non-native speaker, I use these conjunctions almost interchangeably. Among these, I prefer "as", which is easier to say and write. Yet, I have always found "because" clearer. I *have* always wondered whether there was a difference between these two. I should read up more on subordinating conjunctions.